# Sorting indexes of an array in javascript

Tags: javascript, vue.js, ecmascript-6, vuejs2

I'm trying to build a small application on `Vuejs` where I'm having a set of array which comes up through an api response which gives following output:

```
{
    "data":
    {
        "Real Estate Regulatory Act":[
            {
                "id":603,
                "project_id":2392,
                "parent_type":"Real Estate Regulatory Act",
                "type":"Building Plan Approval",
                "name":"FORMS.pdf",
                "link":"https://.....DyumatHotelsFORMS.pdf"
            }
        ],
        "Environmental Clearance":[
            {
                "id":602,
                "project_id":2392,
                "parent_type":"Environmental Clearance",
                "type":"Form 1",
                "name":"HotelsCPEMP.pdf",
                "link":"https://.....MarineandDyumatHotelsCPEMP.pdf"
            }
        ],
        "Document":[
            {
                "id":601,
                "project_id":2392,
                "parent_type":"Document",
                "type":"Land Details",
                "name":"FORMS.pdf",
                "link":"https://....HotelsFORMS.pdf"
            }
        ],
        "Miscellaneous Approvals":[
            {
                "id":604,
                "project_id":2392,
                "parent_type":
                "Miscellaneous Approvals",
                "type":"Not Reported",
                "name":"Report Part 1.pdf",
                "link":"https://...Report Part 1.pdf"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I want to sort this javascript as per the indexes with respect to following array:

```
['Document', 'Environmental Clearance', 'Real Estate Regulatory Act', 'Miscellaneous Approvals']
```

So my final result will be:

```
{
    "data":
    {
        "Document":[
            {
                "id":601,
                "project_id":2392,
                "parent_type":"Document",
                "type":"Land Details",
                "name":"FORMS.pdf",
                "link":"https://....HotelsFORMS.pdf"
            }
        ],
        "Environmental Clearance":[
            {
                "id":602,
                "project_id":2392,
                "parent_type":"Environmental Clearance",
                "type":"Form 1",
                "name":"HotelsCPEMP.pdf",
                "link":"https://.....MarineandDyumatHotelsCPEMP.pdf"
            }
        ],
        "Real Estate Regulatory Act":[
            {
                "id":603,
                "project_id":2392,
                "parent_type":"Real Estate Regulatory Act",
                "type":"Building Plan Approval",
                "name":"FORMS.pdf",
                "link":"https://.....DyumatHotelsFORMS.pdf"
            }
        ],
        "Miscellaneous Approvals":[
            {
                "id":604,
                "project_id":2392,
                "parent_type":
                "Miscellaneous Approvals",
                "type":"Not Reported",
                "name":"Report Part 1.pdf",
                "link":"https://...Report Part 1.pdf"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

My code currently look like:

```
if(response.status === 200)
{
    let docs = response.data.data;
    let sortDocs = ['Document', 'Environmental Clearance', 'Real Estate Regulatory Act', 'Miscellaneous Approvals'];
    let result = []

    sortDocs.forEach(function(key) {
        this.subscProDocument[key] = result.push(docs[key])
    })

}
```

I get error of something like this:

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'subscProDocument' of undefined

I already defined this `subscProDocument` in data() and initialized as an empty array. Help me out with this. Thanks

Comment: why not take the sorted keys array as ordered accessor of the object?

Comment: @NinaScholz can you share some links where I can know more about it.

Comment: @NitishKumar why you need sorting in objects ? when you can access using keys directly ? moreover objects doesen't guaranty order. if you want property to be accessed in the order you have in array. than just loop on array and access each property

Comment: The error is because `this` references the anonymous `function() {}` passed to `forEach()`. You can `bind()` that function to the object that has `subscProDocument` attribute.

Comment: If you want to keep the same structure, you will have to at least change the `data.data` Object to an Array, since the ordering of keys in a JS object is not guaranteed, see my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

```
let data = {
    "data":
    {
        "Real Estate Regulatory Act":[
            {
                "id":603,
                "project_id":2392,
                "parent_type":"Real Estate Regulatory Act",
                "type":"Building Plan Approval",
                "name":"FORMS.pdf",
                "link":"https://.....DyumatHotelsFORMS.pdf"
            }
        ],
        "Environmental Clearance":[
            {
                "id":602,
                "project_id":2392,
                "parent_type":"Environmental Clearance",
                "type":"Form 1",
                "name":"HotelsCPEMP.pdf",
                "link":"https://.....MarineandDyumatHotelsCPEMP.pdf"
            }
        ],
        "Document":[
            {
                "id":601,
                "project_id":2392,
                "parent_type":"Document",
                "type":"Land Details",
                "name":"FORMS.pdf",
                "link":"https://....HotelsFORMS.pdf"
            }
        ],
        "Miscellaneous Approvals":[
            {
                "id":604,
                "project_id":2392,
                "parent_type":
                "Miscellaneous Approvals",
                "type":"Not Reported",
                "name":"Report Part 1.pdf",
                "link":"https://...Report Part 1.pdf"
            }
        ]
    }
};
```

**Get Data from Object and assign to `unordered` variable**

```
const unordered = data.data;
```

**Declare new Variable `ordered`**

```
const ordered = {};
```

`Object.keys` will get the array of `keys` from `unordered object` then will apply `sort function` on keys for `ascending sort`.

Then we'll execute `forEach` loop on `array of keys` and will assign value with key to `ordered object`;

```
Object.keys(unordered).sort().forEach(function(key) {
  ordered[key] = unordered[key];
});

console.log(ordered);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution:

```js
var obj={
    "data":
    {
        "Real Estate Regulatory Act":[
            {
                "id":603,
                "project_id":2392,
                "parent_type":"Real Estate Regulatory Act",
                "type":"Building Plan Approval",
                "name":"FORMS.pdf",
                "link":"https://.....DyumatHotelsFORMS.pdf"
            }
        ],
        "Environmental Clearance":[
            {
                "id":602,
                "project_id":2392,
                "parent_type":"Environmental Clearance",
                "type":"Form 1",
                "name":"HotelsCPEMP.pdf",
                "link":"https://.....MarineandDyumatHotelsCPEMP.pdf"
            }
        ],
        "Document":[
            {
                "id":601,
                "project_id":2392,
                "parent_type":"Document",
                "type":"Land Details",
                "name":"FORMS.pdf",
                "link":"https://....HotelsFORMS.pdf"
            }
        ],
        "Miscellaneous Approvals":[
            {
                "id":604,
                "project_id":2392,
                "parent_type":
                "Miscellaneous Approvals",
                "type":"Not Reported",
                "name":"Report Part 1.pdf",
                "link":"https://...Report Part 1.pdf"
            }
        ]
    }
};

function map(it){
   var item={};
   item[it]=obj.data[it];
   return item;
}

console.log(Object.keys(obj.data).sort().map(map));
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `data.data` object **should be an array if you want to order its items**, as you can't rely on the ordering of keys in an `Object` since it is not guaranteed.
Here is a [post about key ordering in JS objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525795/does-javascript-guarantee-object-property-order)

You can do this ordering and conversion to an array with a single line:

```
data.data = orderedKeys.map(key => ({ [key]: data.data[key] }));
```

This will give you:

```
{
  "data": [
  {
      "Document": [{
          "id": 601,
          "project_id": 2392,
          ...
        }]
    },
    {
      "Environmental Clearance": [{
          "id": 602,
          "project_id": 2392,
          ...
        }]
    },
    {
      "Real Estate Regulatory Act": [{
          "id": 603,
          "project_id": 2392,
          ...
        }]
    },
    {
      "Miscellaneous Approvals": [{
          "id": 604,
          "project_id": 2392,
          ...
        }]
    }
  ]
}
```

Here is a working example:

```js
const data = {
    "data": {
        "Real Estate Regulatory Act": [{
            "id":603,
            "project_id":2392,
            "parent_type":"Real Estate Regulatory Act",
            "type":"Building Plan Approval",
            "name":"FORMS.pdf",
            "link":"https://.....DyumatHotelsFORMS.pdf"
        }],
        "Environmental Clearance": [{
            "id":602,
            "project_id":2392,
            "parent_type":"Environmental Clearance",
            "type":"Form 1",
            "name":"HotelsCPEMP.pdf",
            "link":"https://.....MarineandDyumatHotelsCPEMP.pdf"
        }],
        "Document": [{
            "id":601,
            "project_id":2392,
            "parent_type":"Document",
            "type":"Land Details",
            "name":"FORMS.pdf",
            "link":"https://....HotelsFORMS.pdf"
        }],
        "Miscellaneous Approvals": [{
            "id":604,
            "project_id":2392,
            "parent_type":
            "Miscellaneous Approvals",
            "type":"Not Reported",
            "name":"Report Part 1.pdf",
            "link":"https://...Report Part 1.pdf"
        }]
    }
};

const orderedKeys = ['Document', 'Environmental Clearance', 'Real Estate Regulatory Act', 'Miscellaneous Approvals'];

data.data = orderedKeys.map(key => ({ [key]: data.data[key] }));

console.log(data)
```

Comment: Your `data.data` is an object mate not array

Comment: @Code Maniac, only in the input data, not in the transformed output.

Answer (score 0):

You need to take a reference to `this` as `thisArg` of [`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

```
sortDocs.forEach(function(key) {
    this.subscProDocument[key] = result.push(docs[key]);
}, this);
```

or take an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), which takes `this` of the outer scope.

```
sortDocs.forEach(key => this.subscProDocument[key] = result.push(docs[key]));
```

Comment: Seems that it's in some async callback, so propably `this` in given scope is different that expected, so it's not enough to take reference at this point

Answer (score 0):

```
let obj = {
    "data":
    {
        "Real Estate Regulatory Act":[
            {
                "id":603,
                "project_id":2392,
                "parent_type":"Real Estate Regulatory Act",
                "type":"Building Plan Approval",
                "name":"FORMS.pdf",
                "link":"https://.....DyumatHotelsFORMS.pdf"
            }
        ],
        "Environmental Clearance":[
            {
                "id":602,
                "project_id":2392,
                "parent_type":"Environmental Clearance",
                "type":"Form 1",
                "name":"HotelsCPEMP.pdf",
                "link":"https://.....MarineandDyumatHotelsCPEMP.pdf"
            }
        ],
        "Document":[
            {
                "id":601,
                "project_id":2392,
                "parent_type":"Document",
                "type":"Land Details",
                "name":"FORMS.pdf",
                "link":"https://....HotelsFORMS.pdf"
            }
        ],
        "Miscellaneous Approvals":[
            {
                "id":604,
                "project_id":2392,
                "parent_type":
                "Miscellaneous Approvals",
                "type":"Not Reported",
                "name":"Report Part 1.pdf",
                "link":"https://...Report Part 1.pdf"
            }
        ]
    }
};

const orderedObj = { data: {} };
Object.keys(obj.data).sort().forEach(function(key) {
  orderedObj.data[key] = obj.data[key];
});
```